# Run my app in background for longer time and fetch info

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, background-process

**What i want** : When my app goes in background and user opens any other app then i should be notified that some other app is opened.

**How i am trying to do :** 
Run a thread in background say for 2 hrs, this thread will check what other app is opened.This does not happens always , only when certain condition is met.

**How i am trying to achieve this :** i am using

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier & beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
```

The thread runs endlessly but i dont think its the right way coz apple suggests it should not be done, threads gets killed after 10 mins, however this funda is woking fine for me still i wanna use more secure way to achieve this.

I also checked background modes and some new modes available in ios 7.0 but still cannot find which mode to be used to achieve this [for a particular session/condition, when app goes in background and remains there for 2 hrs i get notification that some other app is opened instead of homescreen].

Any idea how to achieve this.
Just wanna know how to achieve the background work to receive notifications that some other app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

1`- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void(^)(void))handler  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);` 
 So after about 600 seconds your handler Block will be called as your app will be killed soon,
in handler Block you can renew for an other 600 seconds with  `'UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier & beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler'`  and so on……

BUT this might drain the Battery and Apple could not like it!

2- "...to receive notifications that some other app is opened." I DONT THINK APPLE (iOS) WILL LET ANY APP DO THIS!

BUT if "some other app" is an app you control then: 
"one solution to transmit data from one to another app is via URL Schemes" !

[What is Sandbox in ios , Can i Trans data between in one App to Another App in iPhone,if possible how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055990/what-is-sandbox-in-ios-can-i-trans-data-between-in-one-app-to-another-app-in-i)

This will resume ALL the iOS backgrounding modes:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios