# IOS : How can I use one running instance of "background model location" for many applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, app-store, cllocationmanager

Is it possible to create one running  instance of "UIBackgroundModes location" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) for two applications in the same device ( to save battery energy) ?
Use one instance of locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] running for two applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible because of the sandboxing of the applications.
You can find more infos in this answer: [What is Sandbox in ios , Can i Trans data between in one App to Another App in iPhone,if possible how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055990/what-is-sandbox-in-ios-can-i-trans-data-between-in-one-app-to-another-app-in-i)

Comment: thank you , so the one solution is create two applications communicate the result of "background location" with URL shemain ,
can I find problem of  distribution in app Store ?

Comment: Yes, you should use URL schemes. The review result always depends on how you implement it and why you are using UIBackgroundModes location.

Comment: Can we download (from ITunes ) only one app or we must download these two applications ? thanks for your help

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. You can download from iTunes every app that you want but why should you do it?

Comment: if i distribute (in app- store )  two applications communicate with URL schemes  , the user can he download only one app of these applications or he must download these two applications(as they communicate with URL)  ?

Comment: The user can download both app or only one. You should handle both the cases, check out the UIApplication canOpenURL: method to do this.