# control other apps in phone from one app (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, controls

Basically, I want to see if it is possible to control other apps on the user's phone by one single app. The reason for this is so that the user can "turn off" other apps in their phone for a set amount of time, the app would be "unlocked" after the time has ended. I have looked at ScriptingBridge but couldn't find what I was looking for. Thanks for any replies on how I should achieve this.

Comment: No. No without jailbreaking.

Comment: [What is Sandbox in ios , Can i Trans data between in one App to Another App in iPhone,if possible how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055990/what-is-sandbox-in-ios-can-i-trans-data-between-in-one-app-to-another-app-in-i)

Comment: Did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances you cannot control other apps outside of your own app group.  In other words you cannot control FB, Gmail, etc.  However, you could go about this via an installed policy.  This is what say an IT team would do at a company that needs to have some control over the employees device.  This is also how apps that deal in parental controls can block access to apps they don't own, on an iPhone.  You would need of course for the user to download this policy onto their device.  You can add time of day restrictions, etc.