# Is it possible to control http requests and traffic on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

The task is to develop an application for iOS to protect children from inappropriate content. Parents should have the ability to add appropriate site in the list of sites, that is not appropriate for their child.
Is it possible to control all the http (and https) requests and traffic on iOS devices from all applications, including Safari (of course with the permission of the owner of the device)?
By what means it is possible to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Check out iOS Restrictions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304. You can lock down the device to certain apps and block websites in the Safari section.

Comment: Thanks! But, is it possible to set this restrictions by means of app?

Comment: You can do this in your own app by implementing the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method of a UIWebView, but using a standard app store app there's no way to have it affect other apps. In iOS, apps are [Sandboxed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056086/3047919).