# Is AsyncStorage shared across apps?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

My question originates from the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#clear

> AsyncStorage.clear -> Erases all AsyncStorage for all clients, libraries, etc....

does that mean that all apps share the same AsyncStorage?

Comment: AsyncStorage is a simple, unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is **global to the app**. It should be used instead of LocalStorage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AsyncStorage is **not** shared between multiple apps. Every app runs it it's own sandbox environment and has no access to other apps.

To call AsyncStorage.clear only means you will delete all data which your app has stored in AsyncStorage.

That includes

- all data which was stored by a library that uses AsyncStorage like
  https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage
- all data from all users (in case of multi user)

For more information about app sandboxing you can read this answer: 
[What is Sandbox in ios , Can i Trans data between in one App to Another App in iPhone,if possible how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055990/what-is-sandbox-in-ios-can-i-trans-data-between-in-one-app-to-another-app-in-i)