# Security risk of storing access tokens in Async Storage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm building an app with React Native and the app needs to store an access token.

The solution I found is to store the access token in AsyncStorage, but the problem is that the value stored in AsyncStorage is not encrypted.

What are the security risks if the stored values are not encrypted?

For example, if the device is stolen and has an unencrypted disk, someone can access the file system and read the values in the store.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage [is not accessible from other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790764/is-asyncstorage-shared-across-apps).

You would be better off just encrypting the data:
https://medium.com/dev-genius/security-in-react-native-applications-asyncstorage-4a619d923638